# How to check if a calendar event is exception or instance

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API in my application for Recurring events(create, update and delete operations), but i am unable to find if a recurring event is an [instance event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#instances_and_exceptions) or an [exception event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#instances_and_exceptions)

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Creating recurring events is similar to creating a regular (single) event with the event resource's recurrence field set.

```
POST /calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events
...

{
  "summary": "Appointment",
  "location": "Somewhere",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T170000Z",
  ],
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "attendeeEmail",
      # Other attendee's data...
    },
    # ...
  ],
}
```

To see all the instances of a given recurring event you can use the events.instances() request.

The events.list() request by default only returns single events, recurring events, and exceptions; instances that are not exceptions are not returned. If the singleEvents parameter is set then all the individual instances do appear in the result, but not the underlying recurring events.

for more information please see [recurringevents](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dalm,
when we make api request to events.instances(), it will return all the instances of recurring event, but how to find events that are exception(the events that are changed),
like how can i say if a particular event is an exception event

Comment: By checking them against the main event.

Comment: isn't there any better way

Comment: will it work if i Just check the timestamp for the event from api call with older time stamp, instead of checking all the fields?

Comment: @DaImTo Will it be sufficient to check master.sequence != occurrence.sequence? From my tests it looks like exception's sequence is always greater than master sequence. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to identify if the instance is an exception of the recurring event. The only work around is to diff the instance with the master event or use the originalStartTime which uniquely identifies the instance (can compare the originalStartTime with the start objects date/dateTime, though this would fail if you had changed the summary or other text field).

The way I have handled this issue is by making an incremental change request with the nextSyncToken. If an exception was made, an instance will be in the payload that is returned from the list call. I check if that instance has a `recurringEventId` attribute associated with it and if it does, I know that that instance is an exception.

Would highly advocate for Google to include a system similar to that of Microsoft Graph which utilizes an attribute that identifies whether the event is an instance or an exception.

source: https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents